# simultaniously operations in a loop for an arrays of arrays of arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Lets say have an array of the form

```
r=([[[3,2,1],[5,4,1]],[[10,6,3],[5,3,1]],[[9,5,2],[8,4,1]]])
```

And I want to do a subtraction between the elements of each array but getting the following array

```
r=([[[3-3,3-2,3-1],[5-5,5-4,5-1]],[[10-10,10-6,10-3],[5-5,5-3,5-1]],[[9-9,9-5,9-2],[8-8,8-4,8-1]]])

r=([[[0,1,2],[0,1,4]],[[0,4,7],[0,2,4]],[[0,4,7],[0,4,7]]])
```

I have tried loops inside loops but I don't get what I want because I don't know how to restart the value I'm subtracting in each array.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `numpy`? Also, you haven't show your code to get that output for us to assist with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension as following:

```
In [45]: [[[i[0]-j for j in i] for i in sub] for sub in r]
Out[45]: [[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 4]], [[0, 4, 7], [0, 2, 4]], [[0, 4, 7], [0, 4, 7]]]
```